# Is there a way to link a dynamic id to a button when it's called?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I'm trying to create a Raffle button where there's a Modal and the Modal sends information about the raffle, and then a button is at the bottom of the Modal code which sends a message via webhook to sign up for the raffle. However, I don't know how to link the raffleId dynamically to the button...

This is what I had for the Raffle button:

```
const raffleButton = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId(`join-raffle_${raffleID}`)
                .setLabel(" Join Raffle")
                .setStyle("1")
        );

        const webhookClient = new WebhookClient({url: webhookUrl });

        try {
            await webhookClient.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [raffleButton] });
            console.log('Raffle message sent successfully!');
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending raffle message:', error);
          }
```

And in another file, I have the code for the Raffle:

```
module.exports = {
    data: {
      name: `^join-raffle_`
    },
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const guildId = interaction.guild.id;
        const userId = interaction.user.id;
        const keyword = interaction.name.split('_')[1];

        try {
          const joinRaffle = await raffleDB.findOne({
            guildid: guildId,
            _id: keyword,
            expired: false,
        });
...
}
```

I was trying to use wildcards for the name to get it to accept the raffle button custom id, but this doesn't work. Is there any other option I can try? I've tried adjusting things in the handler as well, but not sure what else I can do.

The reason I need customId is because each raffle will have its own id, and it's better to do this dynamically. I also want the button to remain active for the entire life of the raffle, so if I use a temporary button, it will go away.

I thank you for any assistance that can be provided <3

Comment: I would try to create a button, which opens a modal - which on submit passes the provided arguments in fields to message/embed/channel/etc. where you want.

Comment: That's a good idea. I think I will do it that way instead. Thank you